# Nested Resources For Pundit Policy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I'm still trying to wrap my head around Pundit policies. I think I'm close but I've wasted too much time trying to figure this out. My Posts policy works great, but trying to authorize comments, I am getting undefined errors...

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:comment))
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
authorize @comment
    @comment.save

    if @comment.save
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
authorize @comment
end

def update
authorize @comment
    if @comment.update(params[:comment].permit(:comment))
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
authorize @comment
@comment.destroy
redirect_to post_path(@post)
end

private

  def find_comment
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
  end
 end
```

comment_policy.rb

```
class CommentPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  def owned
    comment.user_id == user.id
  end

  def create?
    comment.user_id = user.id
    new?
  end

  def new?
    true
  end

  def update?
   edit?
  end

  def edit?
    owned
  end

  def destroy?
    owned
  end
end
```

The formatting and indenting is a bit off... thats not how I code I swear

```
  class ApplicationPolicy
    attr_reader :user, :post

    def initialize(user, post)
      raise Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, "must be logged in" unless user
      @user = user
      @post = post
    end

    def index?
      false
    end

    def show?
      scope.where(:id => post.id).exists?
    end

    def create?
      false
    end

    def new?
      create?
    end

    def update?
      false
    end

    def edit?
      update?
    end

    def destroy?
      false
    end

    def scope
      Pundit.policy_scope!(user, post.class)
    end

    class Scope
      attr_reader :user, :scope

      def initialize(user, scope)
        @user = user
        @scope = scope
      end

      def resolve
        scope
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: can you show your error details and where it happens?

Comment: I think you should use `record` instead of `comment` in your policy

Comment: not sure what you mean. 
I have no 'record' model, only 'comment, user, and post'

Comment: You inherited from ApplicationPolicy. It instantiates your object as `record`. Notice that you don't have an `#initialize` defined? Because you're using the superclass' instead.

Comment: try changing `  comment.user_id` to `  record.user_id`

Comment: tried that after your first comment. I have tried everything. Is there something else I need to add in the application_policy.rb ?

Comment: can you show your application_policy.rb? And what's the error you get after you change it to `record.user_id`?

Comment: Oh I see. You named it `post`. You need to change it to `post.user_id` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialized your resource in ApplicationPolicy as `@post`. And since your CommentPolicy inherits from ApplicationPolicy and uses its initialization, it only has access to @post. Best option is to keep it as `record`:

```
  class ApplicationPolicy
    attr_reader :user, :record

    def initialize(user, record)
      raise Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, "must be logged in" unless user
      @user = user
      @record = record
    end
    ## code omitted
  end

  class CommentPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
    def owned
      record.user_id == user.id
    end
    ## code omitted
  end
```

Basically you can call it anything you want but `record` makes more sense as it will be used in different policy subclasses.

Comment: Still getting same 'undefined' error after I copied exactly what you have. Post is undefined inside PostPolicy class. Just in case it was not clear, Users have many posts, and posts have many comments.

Comment: You need to change reference to `post` to `record` in your PostPolicy too. Refer to the resource as `record` in all your policy classes.

Comment: FIXED IT THANK YOU!

Comment: Sure. Glad it helped.